# How to modify my strpos statement to target only the exact string

Tags: php, url, strpos

*Warning - I'm a front end designer; Please pardon my fumbling of the PHP concepts here*

So I've got a PHP statement that basically outputs a class in my markup when the URL of the page matches the statement. Here it is:

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/technology") === false) {} else { echo "current"; } ?>
```

As is, I'm using the statement inside a class attribute on an `<a>` tag inside of a `<nav>` element to add a class of "current" so that I can style that `nav` element differently for the page your currently on. As is, it works fine for the site main navigation, because it returns as true even for pages deeper than just `/technology`, such as `/technology/security` which is what I want for the sitewide nav.

The problem is I'd like to use a similar but modified version of this code on subsection navigations that will only appear on the main subpage categories.

So in those cases, I only want the result to be true when the exact URL is matched. More specifically, I want to exclude the parent (ie. `/technology`) even when I'm on `/technology/security`.

So how can I modify the statement to evaluate that way?

Comment: Have you looked at regular expression? http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

Comment: You should probably have a talk with a backend developer / get some basic content management in there that can handle the request info and generate a menu based on a page structure and tell you which on it's on right now... (using regexes and the REQUEST_URI only goes so far)

Comment: Yes, but regex is beyond my experience and scope for this project. Also, I'm using Wordpress on this, and I forgot that WP has a feature for this. DOLP!! Except I'm still not sure it will work for my solution since I'm not planning on adding the subnavs into the Wordpress menus function...but I may have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) function will work much better here, because [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info) let you match the end of the string using the `$` operator.

```
<?php
if(preg_match("%/technology$%", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
    echo "current";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but that empty if is bugging me, you should re-write it to:

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/technology") !== false) { echo "current"; } ?>
```